# check if string is contained in a dataframe column - The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

I downloaded images from imdb and i want to map the images with the imdb id i have in a csv, in order to build a dataframe.
For each image i want to check the filename and check if my dataset contains part of the filename.
My files are jpg and jpeg.
I can have multiple images for a movie.
For example image names can follow the following pattern:

1. tt0000574.jpg
2. tt0000574.jpeg
3. tt0000574_2.jpg
4. tt0000574_4.jpeg

I'm here just interest in the 9 first chars. this code snippet do nothing special except printing.

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    print(filename[:9])
    if(df_temp['imdb_title_id'].str.contains(filename)):
        print(df_temp['imdb_title_id'])
        print (filename)
        print("--------------")
        continue
     else:
        continue
```

I also tried using filter: df_temp[df_temp['imdb_title_id'].str.contains(filename)] based on answers i found on stackoverflow.
My issue is the response error I obtain:
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

here is how my df looks like
[image]

Comment: how does the df_temp['imdb_title_id'] look like?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Python `if` statement which cannot handle a boolean index that is a Series containing multiple values (hence the warning of ambiguity), you can use [`iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) to iterate over the rows and print the contents one by one:

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    print(filename[:9])
    for row in df_temp.loc[df_temp['imdb_title_id'].str.contains(filename)].iterrows():
        print(row['imdb_title_id'])
        print (filename)
        print("--------------")
```